# elasticsearch aggregation: keep information from several fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Problem: I want to do an aggregation on a specific field, keep informations from other fields and get the sum of a metric.

Here the gist with an example: https://gist.github.com/jnaour/33f237b3084d657031bc

I could do a hack to solve this problem: concatenate all information in a single field use a term aggs on this field and sum on the count...
Other possibility: several hierarchical term aggs to keep all the infos.

Is there a neat way to do what I want?

Julien

Comment: Can you add what is the output you are expecting too ?

Comment: Gist updated. I would like to have information about station: name, lat, lon inside the aggregation results.

Answer (score 0):

top hits aggregation would be the best option out there.
Try the below -

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "station.name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "singleSample": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        },
        "total": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is several station with the same name but not the same lat, lon. I probably have to improve my documents before questioning aggregation. Thx anyway.